# Sync error: "SQL Server change tracking has cleaned up tracking..."

Tags: c#, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm using SQL CE 3.5, Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe 3.1 and MSSQL 2008 and for every insert i catch the same exception with ApplyChangeFailed event on ServerSyncProvider.

I have got this error thrown for every insert made with synchronization: "SQL Server change tracking has cleaned up tracking information for
table ''''%s''''. To recover from this error, the client must reinitialize its local database and try to synchronize again."

I got this piece of SQL when inserting row: "IF CHANGE_TRACKING_MIN_VALID_VERSION(object_id(N''[TargetMetricValue]'')) >
@sync_last_received_anchor RAISERROR (N''SQL Server change tracking has cleaned up tracking information for
table ''''%s''''. To recover from this error, the client must reinitialize its local database and try to synchronize again.'',
16,3,N''[TargetMetricValue]'')" and got this: "@sync_last_received_anchor=0"

CHANGE_TRACKING_MIN_VALID_VERSION(object_id(N''[TargetMetricValue]'')) returns 146113 and as it is greater than 0 the above exception is thrown.

On ServerSyncProvider class method ApplyChanges is called => serverSyncProvider.ApplyChanges(groupMetadata, dataSet, syncSession);

groupMetadata.NewAnchor = null, groupMetadata.TablesMetadata[0].LastReceivedAnchor.Anchor = null, groupMetadata.TablesMetadata[0].LastSentAnchor.Ancor = byte[]{127,35,6,0,0,0,0,0}

I bet LastReceivedAnchor is related to sync_last_received_anchor but I dont get any valid value after calling syncAgent.Synchronize()

Also on SqlCeClientSyncProvider method GetTableReceivedAnchor I get null and for GetTableSentAnchor I get value byte[]{127,35,6,0,0,0,0,0}.

So what may be missing that I get null (0) for that value?

**UPDATE according to the first comment:**

I have initial CE db file xyz.sdf It's connection string is declared in app.config as:
'add name="localConnection" connectionString="Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Data\xyz.sdf;Max Database Size=3968" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"'

It's initialized with this code:

```
public SyncAgent()
    {
        systemTables = new List<string> {"__syncArticles", "__syncSubscriptions", "__syncTransactions"};
        ClientSyncProvider = new SqlCeClientSyncProvider(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localConnection"].ConnectionString, true);
        LocalProvider = ClientSyncProvider;
        InitializeAllSyncTables();
    }
```

Comment: how did you initialize your client database? did you use the Local Database Cache Wizard to generate the Sync Fx code or did you hand code them?

Comment: It's predefined sdf file, more details in post updates.

Comment: By any chance, have you tried increasing retention and cleanup window ? you may already have looked at  http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/syncgeneral/thread/cc3d49e0-f188-4d93-b2dd-473137ae9fc6  and http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-ce/3911/MSFT-Client-must-reinintialize-database-error

Comment: Its set to 2 days, anyway two sequencial inserts gives this exception two times. I think that server should send anchor (timestamp) to client DB, but it never happens. I will try to clean table declarations in CE db and I will try to synchronize (don't know if it works this way).

Comment: @Aurimas - how are you creating or initializing the client SDF? does it contain rows already before you make it part of the sync process?

Comment: try to set the SyncDirection to Download for the first sync.  Then set it to Bidirectional on the subsequent syncs.

Comment: @AurimasNeverauskas did setting to download for first sync help?

Answer (score 0):

If any body still has a question how to solve this, check this post [Programming Microsoft Synchronization Services for ADO.NET (Devices)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd938879.aspx). This is very helpful, also batching fails for new databases as sync anchor is not found, so find a way to get the client database instantiated before you can do batching on client databases. Or downlaod the sdf file directly on the client database.

I faced same scenario, I wrote two different InitializeNewAnchorCommand() methods, one for batching and other for one shot database sync which can get my database instantiated from the code directly.

here is what I have, it worked for me.

```
try
{
    // Synchronize
    syncStats = syncAgent.Synchronize();
    App.SyncStats = syncStats;
}
catch (SyncException exception)
{
    if (exception.Message.Contains(" Unable to obtain a new server anchor."))
    {                    
        syncSnapShotStats = syncSnapShotAgent.Synchronize();
        App.SyncStats = syncSnapShotStats;
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```